# Combinatorial proof $\binom{2n}{3} = 2 \binom{n}{3} + 2n \binom{n}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Give a Combinatorical Proof for the identity $\binom{2n}{3} = 2 \binom{n}{3} + 2n \binom{n}{2}$

The LHS is pretty easy binomial(2n, 3) represents the number of ways to choose a subset of 3 elements from a set of 2n elements.
I'm struggling with the RHS to find a combinatorial story , I tried to divide the problem into two different problems, any suggestions ?

Comment: Divide your  $2n$ items into 2 groups with $n$ items apiece.  You can pick your 3 items from the first group, or from the second group, or one from the first and 2 from the second, or ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\binom{2n}{3}$ is a the number of group with $3$ animals among a group with $n$ males and $n$ females. But to do such group, you can also take either $3$ males, or 3 females, or 1 male and 2 females, or 2 males and 1 female, which gives $$2\binom{n}{3}+2\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{2},$$
possibilities.

Comment: Hi Surb!, simply answered, thank you ! the idea of using man and women excellent!